# Question about flushing with JPA before a query is called

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, flush

Just a quick question, but is the flush necessary in this code? Note this would be inside of a JPA transaction.

```
User user = new User();
em.persist(user);

em.flush;

User aUser = em.find(User.class,user.getId());
assert(user.equals(aUser));
```

Or is will it work without the flush?

```
User user = new User();
em.persist(user);

User aUser = em.find(User.class,user.getId());
assert(user.equals(aUser));
```

Or same question but a little more involved example:

```
User user = em.find(User.class,id);
user.setName("My Name");
em.merge(user);

em.flush; //Is this line needed?

User aUser = em.createQuery("select u from User where u.name = 'My Name');
assert(user.equals(aUser));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first case flush is needed as long as `User` has an autogenerated id, since it's not assigned before flush. If `id` is not generated, `em.find()` will return the same instance from the persistence context, so flush is not needed.

In the second case explicit flush is not needed because JPA performs flush before executing a query automatically (if flush mode is `AUTO` that is by default, otherwise explicit flush is needed).